# Get the result of Select query into a variable and insert it as a column value in another table

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

```
DECLARE count NUMBER;

SELECT max(to_number(param_code))+1 INTO count from abc where interface_code='PQR' ;

INSERT INTO abc
( INTERFACE_CODE
, PARAM_CODE
, DSCR
, PARAM_CHAR
, PARAM_NUMBER
, PARAM_DATE
, TRGA_CODE
)
VALUES
(  'PQR'
,   count 
,   'xyz'
,   ''     
,  ''        
,   ''         
,   '*'
)
```

I want to execute these 3 statements as a script in Oracle. 
But this is giving me error.

Please help

Comment: The Oracle Error code/message please. You might also think about Oracle `Sequences`

Comment: ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
The symbol "begin" was substituted for "SELECT" to continue.

Comment: I do not want to use a SP for this

Comment: You miss a `BEGIN` after the `DECLARE` block.

Comment: Even if i add BEGIN and END, i get the following errors: ORA-06550: line 18, column 5:
PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 26, column 2:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE
  MY_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(to_number(param_code))+1
  INTO MY_COUNT
  FROM abc
  WHERE interface_code='PQR' ;

  INSERT
  INTO abc
    (
      INTERFACE_CODE ,
      PARAM_CODE ,
      DSCR ,
      PARAM_CHAR ,
      PARAM_NUMBER ,
      PARAM_DATE ,
      TRGA_CODE
    )
    VALUES
    (
      'PQR' ,
      MY_COUNT ,
      'xyz' ,
      '' ,
      '' ,
      '' ,
      '*'
    );
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Comment: It says Pl/SQL created successfully

Comment: BUt data is not inserted in table

Comment: And now, the record has been inserted as well. You can try with a `SELECT` in same SQL Session. And `COMMIT` it, if it is as expected! Only then, it is actually available.

Comment: @user2124167 Thanks, Glad if you would accept it as answer! :)